# Find rows based on position of macro that has multiple buttons

Tags: excel, vba, row

I am trying to build a template in which i can add rows by using a + button (which also creates a - button) and remove a row by using a - button.

[image]

There are multiple - buttons stacked vertically in different rows (e.g. row 16,17,18,19)

When using the following code:

```vb
Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    MsgBox r.Address

End Sub
```

I get K16 when pressing any -button, despite them being in different rows. I suspect this to be due to the other -buttons being copies of the one in row 16.
How can I make it so that it shows the row number of the clicked - button instead of the one in row 16?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If your shapes don't have unique names then this approach will not be reliable.  For use cases like this I'd prefer hyperlink-triggered actions over having to manage multiple buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71543492/478884

Comment: have you named them different names?

Comment: @Tim Williams

Thank you for pointing out the faulty approach to this case. Your suggestion of using hyperlink-triggered actions has solved the problem!